# Error while reading data as transactions

Tags: r

I'm trying to find out association rules from my transactions data.

The format of file looks like:

```
TransactionID |  ProductID
----------------------------
3716280          337
3716280          1512
3714018          963
```

I imported the data using RCmdr and saved it as a dataset. I tried reading it as transactions again by using the command:

```
txn <- read.transactions(transactions, rm.duplicates= FALSE, format=”single”,sep=””,cols=c(1,2));
```

I get an error as: `ERROR: < text>`

I have just started to learn R, Can somebody help ?

Thanks! 
Vinoth

Comment: You have to be more specific. What do you mean by "saved it as a dataset"? What is a dataset here? What is the object "transactions"? Is it a file name?

Comment: It looks like your quotation marks are 'smart quotes'; this probably causes a problem.